# Mathematical Mystery 3

Tags: riddle, knowledge

A cliché American sees me as tasty treat

But I sound like a bull, one you can not eat

A locus is rotated outside the axis in question

Finding my values is such a calculus impression

Name the mathematical concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a

> torus.

A cliché American sees me as tasty treat

> Do(ugh)nut.

But I sound like a bull, one you can not eat

> Taurus.

A locus is rotated outside the axis in question

> A torus is a surface of rotation, obtained by rotating a circle about an axis that doesn't pass through the circle.

Finding my values is such a calculus impression

> I'm not sure exactly what this means, though there are plenty of things that involve both tori and calculus.

Comment: Correct, good job